# Combine two lists to compare (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have two columns in my excel sheet, example below:-

```
typeA       typeB

cat         product
fish        organs
chicken     slaughter
goat        live
```

I need to combine the cells in each column with each other, like this:-

```
typeC

cat_product
cat_organs
cat_slaughter
cat_live
fish_product
fish_organs
...
...
goat_slaughter
goat_live
```

I know we can use CONCATENATE to combine the cells, but how do i iterate it among the two columns? Each value in the cells in column typeA must be combined with each value in the cells in column typeB.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, @antsemot - if either of our answers helped, don't forget to vote them up and/or accept an answer, so that others can learn from them.

Comment: Thanks for the 'accept', @antsemot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code creates an array (MyArray) with all the values you need.  You can manipulate this array however you like.

```
Sub Combine()
Dim MyArray() As String
Dim i, k As Integer
Dim msg As String

Array1 = Array("cat", "fish", "chicken", "goat")
Array2 = Array("product", "organs", "slaughter", "live")

i = 1

k = (UBound(Array1) + 1) * 4

ReDim MyArray(1 To k)

For Each x In Array1

    For Each y In Array2

        MyArray(i) = x & "_" & y

        i = i + 1

    Next

Next

'display the results in a MsgBox    

For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
    msg = msg & MyArray(i) & vbNewLine
Next i

MsgBox msg

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `cat` is in A3, copy B3:B6 to C1 and Paste Special, Transpose. Then in C3:

```
=$A3&"_"&C$1
```

and copy across and down to suit.